# ember-cli support for Handlebars @vars in each helper (i.e., @index, @key, @first, @last)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I am getting a compilation error in ember-cli whenever I have a Handelbars template that uses @vars variables (i.e., @index, @key, @first, @last) inside of the each helper.  (See http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration for documentation on these @vars variables inside the each helper.)  Below is a simple application built using ember-cli and containing only two files added to the program: routes/application.js and templates/application.hbs.  At the bottom of this post is a screenshot of the compilation error message given by ember-cli.  Is there an error in my code?  Or is this a bug I should report on github  @ https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli?

routes/application.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
    }
});
```

templates/application.hbs

```
{{#each model}}
  {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Screenshot of ember-cli compilation error message:
[image: Screenshot of ember-cli compilation error message]

Here are the versions of the various tools involved:

- ember-cli: 0.0.40
- node: 0.10.30
- npm: 1.4.21
- Handlebars: 1.3.0
- Ember: 1.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That really isn't related to ember-cli.  Ember Handlebars doesn't support the @keyword items.

Comment: Thanks, that was news to me.  Your comment helped lead me to this related article: http://mozmonkey.com/2014/03/ember-getting-the-index-in-each-loops/

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to mimic behavior of following Handlebars keywords: `@index`, `@key`, `@first`, `@last`.

## @index

```
{{#each array as |item index|}}
  Index of item: `{{item}}` is: `{{index}}`
{{/each}}
```

## @key

```
{{#each-in object as |key value|}}
  {{key}}: {{value}}
{{/each-in}}
```

## @first

You could also mimic behavior of `@first` using [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon and taking advantage of `eq` helper - thanks to **kristjan reinhold** for this idea:

```
{{#each array as |item index|}}
  {{#if (eq index 0)}}
    <!-- first element specific html -->
  {{else}}
    <!-- other html -->
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

*Instead of `(eq index 0)` you can use `(eq item array.firstObject)`.*

## @last

As **dwickern** suggested you can use [`Ember.Array.lastObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property_lastObject) to mimic @last behavior.

```
{{#each array as |item|}}
  {{#if (eq item array.lastObject)}}
    <!-- last element specific html -->
  {{else}}
    <!-- other html -->
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Isn't you `{{if}}` an `{{#if}}`?

Comment: To add, you can implement `@last` with `(eq item array.lastObject)`