# How to set active class in first item of loop?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 2.2.0
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.2.1
DEBUG: jQuery            : 1.11.3
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Although Ember is using `Handlebars`, and  `Handlebars` has [built in support for loop operators](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html), there is not support for `@index`, `@first`, `@last` in `Ember` (no idea how this feature has been lost)

(the syntax for `each` loops has changed several times, so I am maybe using outdated examples here)

I am unable to code this:

```
  {{#each model.images as |image| }}
  <div class="item {{if @first "active" }}" data-slide-number="{{@index}}">
    <img src="{{image.image}}">
  </div>
  {{/each}}
```

Which is using:

- [conditionals in attribute bindings](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/conditionals/)
- `@index` and `@first` handlebars operator (not supported in Ember)

A way of accessing the index has [been hacked into ember](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10160) some time ago, so that I can now do:

```
  {{#each model.images as |image index| }}
  <div class="item {{if @first "active" }}" data-slide-number="{{index}}">
    <img src="{{image.image}}">
  </div>
  {{/each}}
```

But that only affects the `@index` replacement. I am unable to find anything about `@first` or `@last`. I could hack it by [using a helper](http://mozmonkey.com/2014/03/ember-getting-the-index-in-each-loops/), but that probably does not work anymore with the current ember version, and if it does, it will surely break in a couple of weeks. And anyway has probably some rough edges which make it unusable.

Or [I could create a controller for my collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19795798/647991) so that I can do all kind of strange things just to get the `.first` or `.last` property. But that really seems too much work just to get such a simple feature.

[Other frameworks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) are supporting this simple feature out of the box. Am I unable to find it, or is it really not supported by Ember?

Comment: I do wish the Ember docs were clearer on this. Handlebars is well-documented, and using Ember I just assume I can use all of Handlebars syntax. But then I find I can only use a subset... and some things are different... but it's hard to know exactly what I can and can't use. Wish Ember's version of Handlebars had documentation of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) to create correct template logic.

```
{{#each model.images as |image index| }}
  <div class="item {{if (eq index 0) "active" }}" data-slide-number="{{index}}">
    <img src="{{image.image}}">
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

For more information see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33681099/2166409) about how to recreate `@index`, `@key` and `@first` Handlebars expressions.

Comment: An extra package? Why not part of Ember? I'll use it, but to tell you the truth I have no hope that this won't break soon.